# Store view base URL in database?

Tags: database, store-view

I have the problem that my main site is not working, while my other store view is working. I have an idea that it might be because the base URL i wrong. Therefore I would like to see the difference between my store views base URLs in the database. How do I find them?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 methods to viewing the base url. (if that is what you are looking for)

Easiest: In the backend go to System > Configuration > Web Then click on the Secure/Unsecure URLS and ensure they are correct.

Method 2: You can view them in the database.Open the database you want, view the table 'core_config_database' and you should see two fields web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url, edit them as you wish but remember the trailing / or they will not work.  Most people use PHPmyAdmin for this but I would suggest locking it to your IP then disabling it once you are done.

Comment: I need to see the base URL for the store views and not the overall base URL :)

Comment: ahh my mistake, this link may be of use then 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup'